# Composer install magento: Class PayPal\Braintree\Console\VaultMigrate does not exist

Tags: composer

we are installing magento and seeing `Composer install magento: Class PayPal\Braintree\Console\VaultMigrate does not exist`

Braintree is neither required neither replaced ...

How can it go missing? Or is something 'not requiring' that was replaced?

```
In ClassReader.php line 26:

  Class PayPal\Braintree\Console\VaultMigrate does not exist
```

Adding via require also does not work

[InvalidArgumentException]
Package magento/module-braintree at version  has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (7.4.11)

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please specify your magento version. In magento 2.4 this module is removed and not used.

Comment: I saw. I needed to flush nginx and php caches. I think PayPal/Braintree still exists right? Before is was Magento/Braintree?

Comment: The module still exists but it does not come bundled with magento 2.4.

Comment: Thanks. I think i got lost with all replace statements from

Comment: Statements from previous versions. A lot gets added then removed and added. It is a long long list. I wish there were a simple : run Magento leave all other stuff out. But add it if you need it. Instead now of installing everything and have to know what to remove.

Comment: You're welcome. For future references you can look at this repo by Yireo https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all/blob/magento-2.4.0/composer.json and check what modules are optional/not required.

Comment: Yep using it. But also here once you start installing extensions then it can conflict. And does not work.